# Run suspend function inside retrofit onResponse method

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, suspend

I can receive data from network by retrofit.this code is hosted in repository class:

```
 fun getQuestionsFromWebServer() {
    val webService = AppModule()
    
    val call = webService.provideModirfaniService().getQuestions()
   
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Question>> {
        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<List<Question>>,
            response: Response<List<Question>>
        ) {
            Log.d("amin", response.body().toString())
            val statusCode = response.code()
            val questionList= response.body()
            if(response.isSuccessful) {
                if (questionList != null) {
                    
                    //This is a suspend function
                    questionDao.updateQuestions(questionList)
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Question>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d("amin", "failed to get questions from network")
        }

    })
}
```

Data should be inserted/updated to DB after receive. `update` method in `DO`:

```
@Update
suspend fun updateQuestions(list: List<Question>)
```

If the code was in my `viewModel` I could run suspend function inside `viewModelScope.launch{}` ,I need to know how to run a suspending  function inside Retrofit `onResponse` method when it is in repository?

(I have not access to `viewModel` or `Activity/Fragment` instance inside repository class )

Comment: can't you use GlobalScope.launch ?

Answer (score 0):

`GlobalScope.launch` seems to be the best fit, since you dont have access to any LifeCycleAware component. from the docs :

> Global scope is used to launch top-level coroutines which are
> operating on the whole application lifetime and are not cancelled
> prematurely.

Please note that any coroutines launched with `viewModelScope` will get canceled when `ViewModel` is cleared, but no such cancellation happens with `GlobalScope` coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

if that data is going to be stored for using somewhere else, you might use CoroutineScope. If data is reload and used only in the same fragment, and is no shared, use lifeCycleScope.